# FFT and accelerometer data: why am I getting this output?

Tags: signal-processing, accelerometer, fft

I have read various posts here at StackOverflow regarding the execution of FFT on accelerometer data, but none of them helped me understand my problem.

I am executing [this](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~ronw/code/MEAPsoft/doc/html/FFT_8java-source.html) FFT implementation on my accelerometer `data` array in the following way:

```
int length = data.size();
double[] re = new double[256];
double[] im = new double[256];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    input[i] = data[i];
}

FFT fft = new FFT(256);
fft.fft(re, im);

float outputData[] = new float[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
    outputData[i] = (float) Math.sqrt(re[i] * re[i]
    + im[i] * im[i]);
}
```

I plotted the contents of `outputData` (left,) and also used R to perform the FFT on my data (right.)
[image: FFT]

What am I doing wrong here? I am using the same code for executing the FFT that I see in other places.

EDIT: Following the advice of @PaulR to apply a windowing function, and the link provided by @BjornRoche (http://baumdevblog.blogspot.com.br/2010/11/butterworth-lowpass-filter-coefficients.html), I was able to solve my problem. The solution is pretty much what is described in that link. This is my graph now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNdag.jpg

Comment: Can I ask why you are applying the FFT to accelerometer data? At least in audio, people usually seem to apply it when something better exists.

Comment: @BjornRoche I'm applying it to accelerometer data to find out what is the fundamental frequency of a limb's tremor, for example. It is useful to analyze diseases such as Parkinson's and essential tremor.

Comment: You may find this useful. http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html Also, consider other techniques such as auto-correlation.

Comment: I am also working on an (open source) project to analyze data collected from a person with Parkinson's disease.  I am having the exact same issue but applying a window function didn't help as much. If you wouldn't mind looking at my code or sending me yours to look at I would be grateful: my email is uberscientist@gmail.com, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The low frequency artefacts are probably due to a lack of windowing. Try applying a window function.

The overall shift is probably due to different scaling factors in the two different FFT implementations - my guess is that you are seeing a shift of 24 dB which corresponds to a difference in scaling by a factor of 256.

Comment: I don't understand what you say here: "The overall shift is probably due to different scaling factors in the two different FFT implementations - my guess is that you are seeing a shift of 24 dB which corresponds to a difference in scaling by a factor of 256."

But applying a windowing function, Blackman window in my case, worked pretty well. Now I'm following the reading suggested by @BjornRoche to improve what I'm doing.

Thank you very much!

Comment: OK - different FFT implementations may take different approaches to scaling - some have a factor of N in the FFT and 1 in the IFFT, some vice versa, and some sqrt(N) on both. So if you see e.g. a factor of N difference between two different FFTs then this may be the explanation.

Answer (score -2):

Because all your data on left are above 0, for frequency analyze it is a DC signal. So after your fft, it abstract the DC signal out, it is very hugh. For your scene, you only need to cut off the DC signal, just preserve the signal over 0 Hz(AC signal), that makes sense.