# Accelerometer with FFT - strange output

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, accelerometer

After reading a lot of research and works on subject I still have got problems applying FFT to my accelerometer data. Most of my code is taken from official MATLAB example: [FFT for one dimension](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/fast-fourier-transform-fft.html#brenuoh-1). After more reading I've found this question: [FFT and accelerometer data: why am I getting this output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007071/fft-and-accelerometer-data-why-am-i-getting-this-output) where there was suggestion to use windowing. So after some more reading I've added hamming window to my code.

My data looks like that on plot:
[image]

And this is the code that I am using for FFT:

```
fs = 1/0.02; %0.02 comes from picking sample each 20ms
m = size(data,1);
w = hanning(m);
yw = w.*data;
n = pow2(nextpow2(yw));
y = fft(yw,size(n,1));
f = (0:size(n,1)-1)*(fs/size(n,1));
power = y.*conj(y)/size(n,1);
figure
plot(f,power)
```

The problem is that my plot from this code looks like that:
[image]

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code? To be honest I'd excepted it would look better (something like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNdag.jpg) so that's why I am asking this question.

**EDIT:**
My data can be found here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58774274/exp.txt

Comment: change `n = pow2(nextpow2(length(yw)));` and `fft(yw,n)` see if there is any improvement.

Comment: Your `f` also has problems. If you could share your data it would be easier to help.

Comment: @Kamtal Changing the given lines didn't make any improvement - the plot was empty (the axis were visible). I've added my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Fs` is `50` so the highest frequency in your data can be `Fs/2 = 25Hz`.

See if this code helps.

```
fid = fopen('1.txt','r');
C = textscan(fid, '%f');
fclose(fid);
data = C{1};
fs = 50;
m = length(data);
nfft = 2^nextpow2(m);
y = fft(data,nfft)/m;
f = fs/2 * linspace(0,1,nfft/2+1);
power = abs(y);
subplot(211)
plot(f,power(1:nfft/2+1)) 
t = (0 : m-1)/fs;
s0 = .8*fs : 3.2*fs;  % .8 sec to 3.2 sec
p(s0) = .5*cos(2*pi*3.3*t(s0)+.25*pi); 
p = p + mean(data); 
subplot(212)
plot(t,data);hold on
plot(t,p,'r')
```

[image]

This is your data in frequency domain.

There is a peak at `3.3 Hz`.

As a proof I plotted a sinusoidal with frequency of `3.3 Hz` along with your data,

As you can see, it totally matches your data.

Comment: This code results in this: http://imgur.com/Mwk1GFx So I don't thing it is correct.

Comment: Ok, thank you - you are right. So now I see that it gives me no sense at all - you are right it's not code but data ;)

Comment: @sebap123, your sampling frequency is much more than your highest frequency element that's why the plot look empty! and it's okey

Comment: Thank you once again. If it is not a problem can you explain me what is t in your code? Or best show whole code that you used?

Comment: @sebap123, I added the code, good luck. I just wanted you to see there are important things in that plot, which you thought had nothing!

Answer (score 2):

Your plots will look better if you first remove the DC offset (subtract the average of all samples from each point before computing the FFT), and then plot only half the FFT result data points (N/2) or less (since the upper half of an FFT result is just a conjugate mirror of the first half for real data input).

Answer (score 1):

What your reference plot shows is just the magnitude on a logarithmic scale (in dB). Also it seems that the DC offset is removed. So you end up with something like this if you adapt it in your code.

```
data = data-mean(data); % DC removal
fs = 50;
m = length(data);
nfft = 2^nextpow2(m);
y = fft(data,nfft)/m;
f = fs/2 * linspace(0,1,nfft/2+1);
power = abs(y);
plot(f,10*log10(power(1:nfft/2+1))); % plot log magnitude
ylim([-30 0]) %limit axis
```

Looks at least similar to me.

[image]

If you additionally take the absolute square you are basically estimating the power spectral density of your signal. So meaning you have to change `power = abs(y);` to `power = abs(y.^2);` and then obviously have to adapt your `ylim([-30 0])` to something lower like -50.